# Difference between os.close(0) & sys.stdin.close()

Tags: python, cgi, stdin, file-descriptor, sys

I'm working on some Python code which is a CGI script called from Apache.

The first thing the code does is (I believe) attempt to close stdin/stdout/stderr with the following:

```
    for fd in [0, 1, 2]:
    try:
        os.close(fd)
    except Exception:
        pass
```

Normally this works, however if they're not open, I get a "python.exe has stopped working", "A problem caused the program to stop working correctly" error message (Win32 exception).

Couple of questions:

- What's the difference between closing via os.close(descriptor number) and sys.stdin.close() etc.
- Assuming I should be closing via both mechanisms, how can I check that the descriptor is actually open (i.e. invoking os.close won't cause Python to crash)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know for sure, but I would bet that `os.close()` is just a python wrapper for the OS's `close()` system call. Python file objects handle some cool stuff for the user like internal buffering of data and whatnot and this is taken care of when calling its `close()` method.

Eventually, the OS's `close()` system call will be called on the File object's file descriptor. So, calling `sys.stdin.close()` at some point is equivalent to calling `os.close(sys.stdin.fileno())`

According to the docs, you can call the `close()` method on a file multiple times and Python won't care. File objects even provide an attribute, `closed` to check if a file is open or not:

```
>>> import os

>>> f = open(os.devnull)
>>> f.close()
>>> f.close()
>>> f.close()
>>> f.close()
>>> f.close()
>>> print f.closed
True
```

If possible, I would suggest calling the sys.FD's `close()` method as it's cleaner and more pythonic.

### Update

#### After looking at the source for python, I found this for file objects (`fileobjects.c`):

```c
static PyObject *
file_close(PyFileObject *f)
{
    PyObject *sts = close_the_file(f);
    if (sts) {
        PyMem_Free(f->f_setbuf);
        f->f_setbuf = NULL;
    }
    return sts;
}

PyDoc_STRVAR(close_doc,
"close() -> None or (perhaps) an integer.  Close the file.\n"
"\n"
"Sets data attribute .closed to True.  A closed file cannot be used for\n"
"further I/O operations.  close() may be called more than once without\n"
"error.  Some kinds of file objects (for example, opened by popen())\n"
"may return an exit status upon closing.");
```

#### Inside close_the_file(f);

```c
static PyObject *
close_the_file(PyFileObject *f)
{
    int sts = 0;
    int (*local_close)(FILE *);
    FILE *local_fp = f->f_fp;
    char *local_setbuf = f->f_setbuf;
    if (local_fp != NULL) {
        local_close = f->f_close; // get fs close() method

        /* SOME CONCURRENCY STUFF HERE... */

        f->f_fp = NULL;
        if (local_close != NULL) {
            f->f_setbuf = NULL;
            Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
            errno = 0;
            sts = (*local_close)(local_fp); // Call the close()
            Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
            f->f_setbuf = local_setbuf;
            if (sts == EOF)
                return PyErr_SetFromErrno(PyExc_IOError);
            if (sts != 0)
                return PyInt_FromLong((long)sts);
        }
    }
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

#### What is the file's close() method?

```c
static PyObject *
fill_file_fields(PyFileObject *f, FILE *fp, PyObject *name, char *mode,
                 int (*close)(FILE *))
{
    ...
    f->f_close = close;
    ...
}
```

#### And for the os module (which uses `posixmodule.c`):

```c
/* This file is also used for Windows NT/MS-Win and OS/2.  In that case the
   module actually calls itself 'nt' or 'os2', not 'posix', and a few
   functions are either unimplemented or implemented differently.  The source
   assumes that for Windows NT, the macro 'MS_WINDOWS' is defined independent
   of the compiler used.  Different compilers define their own feature
   test macro, e.g. '__BORLANDC__' or '_MSC_VER'.  For OS/2, the compiler
   independent macro PYOS_OS2 should be defined.  On OS/2 the default
   compiler is assumed to be IBMs VisualAge C++ (VACPP).  PYCC_GCC is used
   as the compiler specific macro for the EMX port of gcc to OS/2. */

PyDoc_STRVAR(posix_close__doc__,
"close(fd)\n\n\
Close a file descriptor (for low level IO).");

/*
The underscore at end of function name avoids a name clash with the libc
function posix_close.
*/
static PyObject *
posix_close_(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    int fd, res;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "i:close", &fd))
        return NULL;
    if (!_PyVerify_fd(fd))
        return posix_error();
    Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
    res = close(fd);  // close the file descriptor fd
    Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
    if (res < 0)
        return posix_error(); // AKA raise OSError()
    Py_INCREF(Py_None);
    return Py_None;
}
```

#### If the file descriptor has already been closed, then an `OSError` is raised:

```c
static PyObject *
posix_error(void)
{
    return PyErr_SetFromErrno(PyExc_OSError);
}
```

So, calling `os.close(fd)` should raise an OSError if called twice on the same file descriptor. Calling `file.close()` eventually calls `fclose(FILE *f)` and will handle it being called multiple times.

Comment: The developer who wrote the code I'm working on really knew what he was doing (however he's left the organisation so I can't ask him). I suspect he had a reason for doing it the way he did.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that perhaps they switched the FDs of std in, out, and err using `os.dup` and `os.dup2` and are closing the files that point to those FDs. You could try using `os.fdopen()` on the FDs then to get a File object and then call its `close()` method, but that's kinda dumb since calling `os.close()` should work. If neither `os.dup` or `os.dup2` have been called, then std in, out, and err should still point to FDs 0, 1, and 2 respectively.

Comment: I'll leave the question open for a while to see if anyone else chimes in, otherwise will accept your answer.