# os.close() kills the python script without an exception

Tags: python

The following script:

```
import os

def call_close(fd):
    try:
        print fd
        os.close(fd)
    except Exception as e:
        print 'Exception:', e

for fd in range(10):
    call_close(fd)
```

prints

```
0
1
```

Nothing more. No exception. Any guess what is happening?

Comment: possible related to this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173998/difference-between-os-close0-sys-stdin-close

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`os.close`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html#os.close):

> Close file descriptor `fd`.

Closing `fd = 1` closes `STDOUT` so you will not see any more output.

Comment: Great. My real problem was that the logging stop working but the reason was the same.

Answer (score 5):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) (emphasis mine):

> File descriptors are small integers corresponding to a file that has
>   been opened by the current process. For example, standard input is
>   usually file descriptor 0, **standard output is 1**, and standard error is
>   2.

The script isn't terminating; you're closing `standard output`, so anything printed after that line can't be displayed.